# Правильно ли я модифицировал WordPress плагин WP-PostRatings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Имеется плагин [WP-PostRatings](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/), который позволяет выводить звёздочки голосования за статью. На сайт, где он установлен, начали совершаться набеги и злонамеренно ставить по единице множеству статей. Я подумал и решил добавить функционал, чтобы при вставке единицы выводилось сообщение, а оценка не засчитывалась.   В итоге в файле wp-postratings.php изначально имелся такой код:

```
### Function: Process Ratings
add_action('wp_ajax_postratings', 'process_ratings');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_postratings', 'process_ratings');
function process_ratings() {
    global $wpdb, $user_identity, $user_ID;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'postratings')
    {
        $rate = intval($_REQUEST['rate']);
        $post_id = intval($_REQUEST['pid']);

        // Verify Referer
        if(!check_ajax_referer('postratings_'.$post_id.'-nonce', 'postratings_'.$post_id.'_nonce', false))
        {
            esc_html_e('Failed To Verify Referrer', 'wp-postratings');
            exit();
        }

        if($rate > 0 && $post_id > 0 && check_allowtorate()) {
            // Check For Bot
            $bots_useragent = array('googlebot', 'google', 'msnbot', 'ia_archiver', 'lycos', 'jeeves', 'scooter', 'fast-webcrawler', 'slurp@inktomi', 'turnitinbot', 'technorati', 'yahoo', 'findexa', 'findlinks', 'gaisbo', 'zyborg', 'surveybot', 'bloglines', 'blogsearch', 'ubsub', 'syndic8', 'userland', 'gigabot', 'become.com');
            $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            foreach ($bots_useragent as $bot) {
                if (stristr($useragent, $bot) !== false) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
            $rated = check_rated($post_id);
            // Check Whether Post Has Been Rated By User
            if(!$rated) {
                // Check Whether Is There A Valid Post
                $post = get_post($post_id);
                // If Valid Post Then We Rate It
                if($post && !wp_is_post_revision($post)) {
                    $ratings_max = intval(get_option('postratings_max'));
                    $ratings_custom = intval(get_option('postratings_customrating'));
                    $ratings_value = get_option('postratings_ratingsvalue');
                    $post_title = addslashes($post->post_title);
                    $post_ratings = get_post_custom($post_id);
                    $post_ratings_users = ! empty( $post_ratings['ratings_users'] ) ? intval($post_ratings['ratings_users'][0]) : 0;
                    $post_ratings_score = ! empty( $post_ratings['ratings_score'] ) ? intval($post_ratings['ratings_score'][0]) : 0;
                    // Check For Ratings Lesser Than 1 And Greater Than $ratings_max
                    if($rate < 1 || $rate > $ratings_max) {
                        $rate = 0;
                    }
                    $post_ratings_users = ($post_ratings_users+1);
                    $post_ratings_score = ($post_ratings_score+intval($ratings_value[$rate-1]));
                    $post_ratings_average = round($post_ratings_score/$post_ratings_users, 2);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_users', $post_ratings_users);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_score', $post_ratings_score);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_average', $post_ratings_average);

                    // Add Log
                    if(!empty($user_identity)) {
                        $rate_user = addslashes($user_identity);
                    } elseif(!empty($_COOKIE['comment_author_'.COOKIEHASH])) {
                        $rate_user = addslashes($_COOKIE['comment_author_'.COOKIEHASH]);
                    } else {
                        $rate_user = __('Guest', 'wp-postratings');
                    }
                    $rate_user = apply_filters( 'wp_postratings_process_ratings_user', $rate_user );
                    $rate_userid = apply_filters( 'wp_postratings_process_ratings_userid', intval( $user_ID ) );

                    // Only Create Cookie If User Choose Logging Method 1 Or 3
                    $postratings_logging_method = intval(get_option('postratings_logging_method'));
                    if($postratings_logging_method == 1 || $postratings_logging_method == 3) {
                        $rate_cookie = setcookie("rated_".$post_id, $ratings_value[$rate-1], apply_filters('wp_postratings_cookie_expiration', (time() + 30000000) ), apply_filters('wp_postratings_cookiepath', SITECOOKIEPATH));
                    }
                    // Log Ratings No Matter What
                    $rate_log = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->ratings} VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s, %s, %d )", 0, $post_id, $post_title, $ratings_value[$rate-1], current_time('timestamp'), get_ipaddress(), @gethostbyaddr( get_ipaddress() ), $rate_user, $rate_userid ) );
                    // Allow Other Plugins To Hook When A Post Is Rated
                    do_action('rate_post', $rate_userid, $post_id, $ratings_value[$rate-1]);
                    // Output AJAX Result
                    echo the_ratings_results($post_id, $post_ratings_users, $post_ratings_score, $post_ratings_average);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    printf(esc_html__('Invalid Post ID (#%s).', 'wp-postratings'), $post_id);
                    exit();
                } // End if($post)
            } else {
                printf(esc_html__('You Had Already Rated This Post. Post ID #%s.', 'wp-postratings'), $post_id);
                exit();
            }// End if(!$rated)
        } // End if($rate && $post_id && check_allowtorate())
    } // End if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'postratings')
}
```

Я его модифицировал таким образом:

```
...TTP_USER_AGENT'];
                foreach ($bots_useragent as $bot) {
                    if (stristr($useragent, $bot) !== false) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
if($rate < 2) {
                printf(__('<span class="mess"><strong>Напишите в комментариях, почему статья заслуживает единицы. Мы её улучшим.</strong></span>'), $post_id);
                exit();
            }
                header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
                $rated = check_rated($post_id);
                // Check Whether Post...
```

Сообщение выводится. Но я думаю, что я не совсем правильно сформировал строчку вывода, т.к. для указанного в ней текста априори нет перевода.
И в целом не нарушал ли я функционал? По тестам вроде всё работает так, как нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Функционал вы не нарушили. Есть перевод, нет его - это ни на что не влияет. Кроме самого перевода.